# report error , menu not found

Tags: edit-mode

I am getting *Report error menu not found* when I right click in edit mode to get the vertex content menu.

I deleted blender and reinstalled and I am having the same problem , would really appreciated any tip to solve this.

I am using Blender 2.91.2 on a Macbook pro 10.7.15 Catalina

[image]

Comment: Tks Duarte Farragota for editing my question :) and making it easier to understand , unfortunatly like all  previous ones I got  no answer:( I am totally new here , is there anything I should do to get a proper answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys solved it:)!  I just  loaded factory settings inside blender preference.

Click Edit choose  Preference
Press on hamburger menu at the bottom left and choose load factory preferences.